# How to speed up a block-matching algorithm using CUDA or OpenCL?

Tags: python, algorithm, image-processing, cuda, gpgpu

I am wondering how I could speed up my Python block-matching algorithm using CUDA or OpenCL as such an algorithm should be highly parallalelizable. Currently, my algorithm works as follow:

```
For some blocks B1_i of the first image:
  For blocks B2_j (in the neighborhood of B1_i) in the second image:
    Find the block which minimizes the distance d(B1_i,B2_j)
```

As my code currently takes about 1 hour, I would like to avoid the first loop i.e. I want to process all my B1_i blocks in a parallelized way.

However, when I try to find the most similar block on the second image, I need to use some specific functions such as a Kernel Density Estimation using scikit-learn, so this part should ideally be written in Python.

Do you think that it is a "clever" approach?

EDIT:

I have profile my code and I have realized that the slowest part is the joint histogram estimation. So far, I have used gaussian kernel density estimation through scikit-learn (KernelDensity) to do so and it seems that the numpy histogram2d function is faster. However, I think I could still improve the speed of such a part but I'm wondering how.

Do you think that rewritting the 2D joint histogram in a low-level language such as C or C++ could help?

Answer (score 2):

Keep your blocks static for one of the images (example: block_1 will always be x:0 y:0 w:64 h:64, and 2 will be x:64 y:0 w:64 h:64) and for the other image create all possible blocks based on your neighborhood threshold.

```
For y = -NeighborHoodThresholdY To NeighborHoodThresholdY
    For x = -NeighborHoodThresholdX To NeighborHoodThresholdX
        // parallelize
        FOr Each block2 In image2
            // separate thread / task / kernel
            block1 = image1.Region(block2.X + x, block2.Y + y, block2.Width, block2.Height)
            Compare(block1, block2)
        Next
    Next
Next
```

Comment: How/why such an implementation will be faster ?

Comment: @neon29 - It's just a guess, without your actual code, or actual performance testing/profiling/benchmarks who knows. I don't even know what problem your trying to solve (finding similarities between 2 images, why blocks? why not image hashing and only searching if the hashs are very similar?, there could be a more efficient way to solve your actual problem than any parallelized version of this algorithm. In any case without details we'll never know.

Comment: Global methods using a similarity metric and an optimization method have been proven to be inefficient in my context (due to huge variation in the images because of point of view, speckle,...). I have tested a full search (no optimization) with mutual information and other similarity measures but I never found any maxima.

Comment: Using such a similarity metric but with a block-matching algorithm (with blocks centered on salient points) return good results once I filter the resulting vector field. I could post my code tomorrow ;). I am also trying to use multiprocessing to speed up the code. As I'm just prototyping I hope I could keep working with such a prototyping language.